# Hadoop logging on Mac going to console.. any setting to have it go to Hadoop's log files instead?

Tags: logging, console, hadoop

When I run a command for Hadoop on my Mac, Hadoop sends the logs to the command line.  I could capture this on my own with `> mylogfile.log`, but I'm hoping there is simply a setting/option in Hadoop or Apache-logging that changes how this works.

Thanks!

**Update**: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725858/can-apache-httpd-be-made-to-log-errors-to-console-instead-of-log-files-under-wind that has a suggestion on how to fix it for Apache.  Since the two use the same logging system, maybe this will help someone suggest a way to set something similar?